# using Xdebug's bundled debugclient, example of how to set both local and global variables while stepping through a page

Tags: xdebug

I am using Centos 7.6 with a locally installed apache httpd.service. I have installed xdebug v2.9.1 and verified its configuration with a simple phpInfo() test page.

When i load the page via a localhost reference in a local browser, I can start 'debugclient' and step_into, step_over, status, and various other xdebug protocol commands.

```
<?php
  $a = 0;
  echo "a= " . $a . PHP_EOL;
  $a += 1;
  echo "a= " . $a . PHP_EOL;
  $a += 1;
  echo "a= " . $a . PHP_EOL;
  $a += 1;
  echo "a= " . $a . PHP_EOL;
  echo "Done" . PHP_EOL;
```

Can some informed person please provide me with an example of a command to set/create a variable and to change its value from the debugclient command line? Specifically, in my example file: How to modify the value of '$a', so as to change the values that are reported via the echo statements?

Yes. I understand there are other debuggers besides 'debugclient', but i am trying to understand the communication protocol between the IDE and website host, as it specifically applies to Xdebug and the DBGP protocol; especially since the provided Xdebug documentation does not provide an example of using 'eval', 'expr', and 'exec' at https://xdebug.org/docs/dbgp

I tried to create tags 'debugclient' and 'DBGP Protocol' but apparently don't have enough 'reputation' to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `property_set -i 45 -n $a -- base64encodedvalue`

The `base64encodedvalue` should be the value that you want to set, encoded with base64. You can create that value by using `php -r 'echo base64_encode("42");'`, so that the full example becomes:

```
property_set -i 45 -n $a -- NDI=
```